# Wait for message to be received? with msgrcv c++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I'm using msgsnd and msgrcv and I'm wondering how to wait for the message to be sent before receiving?

i.e.

Process A signals a semaphore to let Process B do his thing,

Process B sends a message,

Process A receives message.

What this is doing is just printing an empty message, because theres nothing telling Process A to wait till B sends it, what's the approach? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Process A is not waiting, you are apparently setting this flag

> **`IPC_NOWAIT`** Return immediately if no message of the requested type is in the queue. The system call fails with `errno` set to `ENOMSG`.

Don't use that flag if you want to wait, or if you want to do useful work while waiting, check `errno` and call again later.